# Breadboard Jumper Shortcuts

Tags: wiring, breadboard

This is my second question relating to this project. I am trying to make this project in the breadboard first, yet I am having trouble connecting all the resistors, and DIP switch connection with as few wires as possibl (I ran out when trying to recreate it.

[image]

If possible try to explain it in a visible example

Comment: Do you know how the connections on a bread board work? You don't need to use store-bought jumper wires, just get a roll of solid (non-stranded) wire and wire stripper and make your own.

Comment: Could you  show us a picture of your breadboard so we can comment on it?  I think I could build that circuit with very few jumper wires.

Answer (score 3):

Some more information would be helpful in providing a better answer.

Breadboard basics:
[image]

You can save a lot of space by plugging resistors in upright like this:
[image]

I hope you are not looking for a specific "plug this resistor into this breadboard slot" guide. It's much more beneficial to be able to read a schematic and plug wires in on your own. If you need help in understanding how, then say so.